# typeahead auto suggest implementation [comma / Space]

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead, typeahead.js, type-ahead

I have given auto suggestion part in my module using typeahead js . i have done following changes in my part  -

```
$('#input').typeahead({local:["Super","Beautiful","Perfect", "Good Looking"]});
```

while i type like "goodlooking"(without space) value, i need to be display "good looking(with space)" value also in suggestion part. What should i do for this changes.

Advance Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Check out typeahed documentation: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#datum

You should build items like:

```
[
 {
    value: 'Super',
    tokens: ['super']
 },
 {
    value: 'Beautiful',
    tokens: ['beautiful']
 },
 {
    value: 'Perfect',
    tokens: ['perfect']
 },
 {
    value: 'Good Looking',
    tokens: ['goodlooking']
 }
]
```

The individual units that compose datasets are called `datums`. The canonical form of a datum is an object with a `value` property and a `tokens` property. The `value` is the string that represents the underlying value of the datum and `tokens` is a collection of strings that aid *typeahead.js* in matching datums with a given query.